# What weapon would be most effective

Tags: weapons, combat

**EDIT**

I have decided to remove this question as it might affect young people searching online

Apologies to those who have already answered or spent time researching.

I may rewrite the question differently at a later date. I cannot delete the question because there are already answers and the system prevents me. I intend to sleep on this before making a final decision.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120067/discussion-on-question-by-chasly-supports-monica-what-childs-toy-weapon-would).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Fibre optic whip:

[image]

Those fibres are very strong, you may be able to use one as a garotte, but if not, ligature strangulation by pretty lighted rope should do the trick.

#### Or, juggling knives

[image]

I sell these in my own store, and while the edge is slightly dulled, it's still pretty sharp metal. You can draw blood accidentally by handling them wrong.

Answer (score 4):

[image]Video Game Console. It is a toy weapon and you can get online with it and hire a hitman to kill your twin.

[image]

Or, if you want a less bloody fight, use it like in [the 1983 movie Wargames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames) and hack into Norad. Threaten everyone with nuclear destruction if your twin doesn't put down the lawn dart.

Answer (score 2):

Lawn Darts (for obvious reasons) and Bocce Balls (they are really hard) seem the most lethal outside a chemistry set.

[image: Lawn Darts!] [image]

Comment: Are they sold under the "toy *weapons*" section? They are toys but are they toy weapons?

Comment: Since you can't get lawn darts anymore in most places, I'd go with the Bocce Balls. I've been hit by one before, and they definitely pack a punch.

Comment: @TheDaleks, You are right, which is also why I added the bocce balls, but I figured there still had to be some black market darknet place selling the most lethal toy ever made